# Unable to connect to System DSN using Access 365

Tags: ms-access, odbc

I have created a mySQL database on my webhosting site.   I created an ODBC connection for it and I can access it fine with my client tool on my Windows 10 computer. When using Access 365 I can see ODBC connection tab for files and for machine databases but there is none for system DSNs so I can't connect to my MySQL database.
Is there a way to force Access 365 to connect to system DSN?

Comment: sounds like a x32 and x64 bit issue. For this reason, it is a VERY good idea to launch the ODBC manager from Access when you attempt to setup a connection, that way you can be sure that you don't miss-match the connection. by default, the x64 bit OBDC manager is launched if you use windows control panel. So, better to run from Access. And often you need to run/launch access as administrator - and that can often help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system DSNs should show up under the Machine Data Source tab.  Make sure you've created a 32 bit DSN for 32 bit Access or a 64 bit DSN for 64 bit Access.